# Sharepoint CAML Query does not work in IE when searching by Taxonomy Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml, taxonomy

I've the code below:

```
function ReceivePages(FirstFolderProd, FirstFolderWithoutSpaceProd, GetTagFolder){
                var restUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sites/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Páginas')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Produto</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Intranet_SubCategoria' /><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti'>Contas à Ordem</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>\"}";

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: restUrl,
                        async:false,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

I already tried with taxonomy field in google and its working but in IE11 does not. Is not giving me error when I make the query caml simply gives me 0 results

```
var x= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Páginas')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Produto</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}";
```

Google:

[image]
[image]

IE11:
With the same query:

[image]

Any ideas what is the problem?